# Java issues with mantaining copied array list values

Tags: java, arrays, reference, copy, clone

I'm new here, but I have searched for solutions to this issue for a couple hours and even though I kinda found some answers, but none of them actually worked.

I have an Array List called "parents" (of a node in this case) of the type "State" (8 queens arranged in a chess board). I am declaring it like this:

```
ArrayList<State> parents = new ArrayList<State>(3);
```

Likewise, I have a "children" array of states declared like this:

```
ArrayList<State> children = new ArrayList<State>(7);
```

I have to rearrange the state of the board so I don't have any queens in position to attack each other, using the Beam Search method. To do this, I have to copy the state of the parents to the children, randomly rearrange the queens in the children and check if the number of attacks in their states has lowered, rinse and repeat until I get 0 attacks (or the algorithm has gone on long enough without finding a better state than the last).

Finally, after this "contextualization" of the problem, let's go to the Issue per se.

Whenever I change the position of a queen in a child state, it is also changed in the parent state, even though I tried a lot of workarounds to passing an object from an ArrayList to another without copying the references. Right now, I'm doing it like this:

```
ArrayList <State> buffer = new ArrayList<State>(parents);
children.add(buffer.get(m)); //the m here is just so I can choose in a for witch parent will be copied to the children array
```

And then I am changing the queen values like this (not exactly this, but the actual code would require more contextualization and I would digress from the issue even more:

```
children.get(k).board[queen]=k;//basically changing the "Y" position of the queen to a "k" value that comes from a loop.
```

When I change the value of the queen in the children state like this, the parent state is also changed, and this is what I can't for the life of me fix, and I did try using some answers found here before I made this post, like using the clone method, like this:

```
buffer=(ArrayList<State>) parents.clone();
```

or the Collections.copy method:

```
ArrayList<State> buffer = new ArrayList<State>(3);
Collections.copy(buffer, parents);//actually this one gives me an out of bounds error, stating that the source does not fit in the destiny
```

and some others, but all to no avail, the parent values still get modified.

Does anyone have an Idea of what can be done to fix this? Or am I approaching the problem in a way that it can't be fixed? I'm also kinda new to Java so it is possible that I missed something in one of the solutions I've previously found, so if anyone out there is really sure that one of those methods have to work in my case, by all means, explain it and I will try to use it again.

(also, I tried to "build" the post in the better possible way, if anyone have any suggestion on how to formulate my questions in the future, they are also welcome)

Cheers :)

Comment: I can only guess but i believe you might be performing a [Shallow Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy). The clone method too gives you a shallow copy, unless Of course you override the clone method and perform a deep copy(which i doubt you are). Try finding out how to perform a deep copy in java. Might help.